# importing multiple untidy excel sheets and variables

Tags: r, excel, database-design, rstudio, medical

I am struggling with the import of a large and very chaotic excel database. Already tried many functions like readxl etc. but it seems like my database is too complicated.

- i have 96 worksheets in the file (each is one month, database includes multiple years)
- i would like to have them in one large dataframe/tibble
- columns are not always the same. range is from 4 to 10 columns per sheet.
- i would like to import 4 columns per sheet, but their headers are not precise. eg. "DOB" and "Date of Birth" etc.

Does someone know a workaround in readxl or similar to specify the columns it want to import?
Like providing a vector to look out  for while importing?
E.g. column "DOB" in R should contain all variables from columns "DOB", "Date of Birth" or "Birth"
column "Operation" in R should contain all variables from columns "OP", "Operation", or "Procedure" and so on...

Thanks so much in advance! Greets from Innsbruck!

Answer (score 1):

As your input is chaotic, you're never going to get a one-line-fits-every-case solution.

As you've not provided us with any sample data, you're not going to get a definitive solution from StackOverflow.  And, because of the generality of your question, I think you're going to get downvotes and votes to close.  That said, I think your question is reasonable and worthy of some thought.

In the long term, I'd get your suppliers to mend their ways and and provide you with data in a consistent format.  Don't say they need to do this because it makes your life easier.  Sell it to them because it will make your organisation more efficient and make life eassier for everyone: them, you, and your suppliers.

Here's how I would go about the problem in the short term...

I'd write a function to handle each messy workbook separately and make it [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Obviously, this is the major part of the job.  Once you've got that, then the rest of the job is straightforward.  Simply, `lapply()` your function to each workbook and then `bind_rows()` the result.

[As an aside, Excel is not a database.  But that's a discussion for another day.]

Handling the messy column names is relatively easy.  Decide which column names you want to use.  Also decide how you want to handle missing columns: do you want to add a column of `NA`s if a column is missing, report an error or do something else?

Tidyverse offers `rename_with()` which takes a character vector of column names and expects a return value which is also a character vector of the same length containing the new column names.

So a rename columns function might look something like this:

```
renameFunc <- function(cols) {
  newColNames <- c()
  sapply(
    cols,
    function(colName) {
      newName <- case_when(
        colName == "DOB" ~ "DateOfBirth",
        colName == "Birth" ~ "DateOfBirth",
        # And do on for all possible input column names
        TRUE ~ "!! Error"
      )
      if (newName == "!! Error") stop(paste0("Unhandled column name ", colName))
      append(newColNames, newName)
    }
  )
  # Other validation: correct number of columns, add missing columns, etc
  newColNames
}
```

Note the error checking: that's going to be a critical component of your solution to make sure that there aren't any unanticipated features of your input data.

Now you can use the rename function in the function that tidies your data:

```
tidyInputData <- function(fileName) {
  # Read the Excel file
  d <- readxl::read_excel(fileName)
  # Rename the columns
  d <- d %>% rename_with(renameFunc, everything())
  # Other processing to ensure tidy output_column
  # More error checking
  d
}
```

Assuming you have a list of Excel files (from `list.files()`, perhaps), the whole import-and-merge process then becomes

```
mergedData <- bind_rows(
                lapply(
                  fileList,
                  tidyInputData
                )
              )
```

I cannot overemphasise the importance of rigorous error checking in this sort of process.

Comment: Thanks so much, will try to work on this solution and keep you updated!!!